# How to enable datasheet’s filter triangle button in continuous form

Tags: sql, ms-access, vba, ms-access-2010

Is it possible to use the built in triangle button to filter records for datasheet form in continuous forms?

If not. Then do you think if it is possible to code such a feature?

Also, is it possible to add a select all button within the datasheet form itself instead of placing it in a form containing the datasheet as a subform?

I’m afraid I have no choice but to use continuous forms because of how limiting datasheet forms are.

Comment: I don't have a clue what you mean. A datasheet subform can't be present on a continuous form, since continuous forms don't allow subforms. If you just mean "Is there a filter funnel icon on a datasheet form" the answer is yes, it's there by default, and you don't need to do anything to get it there, but just creating one would've shown you that. If you mean "is there a filter icon on a continuous form" the answer is yes also, and you could also just have found that out by creating one.

Comment: Apologies for the misleading question. My question is, is there a way to enable the filter funnel icon for every column in my continuous form?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, this is not an available feature. Also, no workarounds are available.
You can add an image with the filter icon and try to determine if the column is filtered, but that's both very difficult and not very useful (since you can't get the dialog to adjust the filter when you click on it).

If you want the filter dialog, however, you can just right click one of the fields to add a filter or adjust an existing filter.